# Format SDXC card to be compatible with SDHC?

Tags: sdhc, kodak, microsd, sdxc

I bought a [Kodak PIXPRO sp360](https://kodakpixpro.com/support/downloads/resources/cameras/360-vr/sp360/docs/sp360-specsheet-en.pdf) which only supports SDHC. I have a 128 GB SDXC card that I would like to use, even if I must sacrifice all but 32GB.

Is this possible? I tried using `parted` to create a 32G fat32 partition but it hasn't worked.

```
$ sudo parted $dev
mklabel msdos
mkpart primary fat32 1MiB 32G
quit
$ sudo mkfs.vfat $dev
```

Comment: Have you try to put the card as it was (128GB) and check how it is recognized?

Comment: Have you tried making a partition sized LESS than 32G (say 16 or 31)? "32G" might still create a partition size that is exactly above what a 32G limited system can handle.

Comment: @RomeoNinov The camera reports 'sd card error' then offers to format. After it formats and reboots it reports 'sd card error'.

Answer (score 2):

SDHC and SDXC are descriptions of the card formats (Secure Digital High Capacity and eXtended Capacity). SDHC only supports cards of less than 32GB, while SDXC supports cards  with more than 32GB.
If your camera does not support SDXC, nothing you do to the card will make it work properly. The camera *might* see the 128GB card as a 32GB card, but the odds of failure or image corruption are high.
I suspect you are out of luck with the PixPro 360, as it only states support for SDHC.

Answer (score 1):

From Lexar Website:

"SDXC is an SD memory card format that is based on the SDA 3.0 specification. SD and SDHC cards are based on the SDA 2.0 specification. SDXC memory cards use the newer “exFAT” file system that is more efficient for SDXC’s large capacities, while SD and SDHC memory cards use the FAT32 file system. This difference is the reason that the new SDXC format is NOT backwards compatible with host devices that only take SD (128MB to 2GB) or SDHC (4GB to 32GB) cards."

Comment: I formatted the card with a FAT32 file system.

People sell '1TB' sd cards for $5. They have firmware installed that lies about the sd cards size - they report 1TB but really they are 512mb. I hoped I could format my SDXC card or flash a firmware on it that would behave like a 32G SDHC card.